# Need Help-cant figure out how to route to featured homes page without the content overlapping my navbar and search component

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

Need Help-cant figure out how to route to featured homes page without the content overlapping my navbar and search component. i just want it to go to a new url that doesnt import the components unless i want it to. https://github.com/alfonza1/Zillow

i think it may have something to do with my app.component.html idk. i tried everything ic ould and asked chatgpt a bunch of questions. i feel like its a quick fix

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

My advise to use Bootstrap.

Find reference for your UI hero page: https://themes.getbootstrap.com/preview/?theme_id=17532

Step to install Bootstrap to an Angular: (Easy to use)

```
ng add @ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap
```

Ref: https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home

It will include CSS framework as well.